# Div scroll and ::after element outside

Tags: html, css

I have a div menu which has a fixed size (e.g. 100% of the height). The content could be larger. Then it would have to scroll.

```
div {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

There is also an :after element on the div which is positioned absolutely right outside the div.

```
div::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    top: 45%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 5%;
}
```

The problem is that once I add the overflow auto to the div the after element is hidden. How do I get a scrollbar AND have the after element outside the div?
Found some similar questions but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Comment: `width 5%;` should be `width: 5%;`

Comment: Right, I changed that. It's only code to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for now by simply adding another div inside the original one

```
div.original div.inside {
   overflow-y: auto;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100;
}
```

and remove the overflow from the original div. You need one more div, but this seems to be the easiest and cleanest solution.